# Django | Error: sequence item 0: expected str instance, TestQuestion found

Tags: python, django

Al hacer un join para para pasar un array a un string con comas intercaladas devuelve el siguiente error:

**Error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Línea que convierte arrat en un string con "," intercalada:**

```
",".join(newQuestionList)
```

**newQuestionList contiene:**

```
newQuestionList:  <QuerySet [<TestQuestion: 1>, <TestQuestion: 2>, <TestQuestion: 3>, <TestQuestion: 4>, <TestQuestion: 5>, <TestQuestion: 6>, <TestQuestion: 7>, <TestQuestion: 8>, <TestQuestion: 9>, <TestQuestion: 10>]>
```

**Código:**

```
#Selección nuevo string con 10 numbers sin superar
passedQuestionList=UserAnswers.objects.filter(modality__name=questionMod, user=username, correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion__gte=4).values('numberQuestion')  
newQuestionList = TestQuestion.objects.filter(nameModality__name=questionMod).order_by('number').exclude(number__in=passedQuestionList)[:10]
#Guardar nueva lista de 10 números:
stringNumbers=",".join(newQuestionList) #Linea 104 que devuelve error (pasar array a string)
print("Convertido en cadena: ",stringNumbers)
SaveList = TestCounter.objects.get(user=username, modality=modalidadID)
SaveList.listQuestionsNumbers = stringNumbers
SaveList.save()
```

Comment: Debes convertir cada elemento de esa lista en string para que join lo admita. Por ejemplo así: `",".join(map(str, newQuestionList))`

Comment: ¿Qué es map en este caso? El objetivo es unir 10 int que contiene en un sólo string.

Comment: `map(funcion, iterable)` lo que hace es aplicar la función a cada elemento del iterable. En este caso la función que se aplica es `str()` para convertir cada uno de sus elementos en un string. Luego `",".join()` recibirá ya un iterable de strings. Ahora bien, qué aspecto tendrá cada uno de esos strings depende de cómo esté implementada la clase `TestQuestion`. Si solo quieres el número, cabe suponer que cada cuestión tenga un atributo con ese valor, digamos que es `numero`. Entonces podrías hacer `",".join(str(q.numero) for q in newQuestionList)`

Comment: Es genial. La verdad es que me ha parecido avanzada esa linea. Pero es genial, y por cierto, funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias!